Flatpak theming Ubuntu 24.04
Recently I started to move every application possible to Flatpak (even some apt apps) as a tryout.
The installation went all right and without any errors. Then I copied the necessary theme and icon folders to $HOME/.themes and $HOME/.icons, after which I ran the following commands in terminal:
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.themes
sudo flatpak override --filesystem=$HOME/.icons
sudo flatpak override --env=GTK_THEME=Yaru-dark
sudo flatpak override --env=ICON_THEME=Yaru

This set up the theme to every flatpak application as planned, but as a result the margins dropped to 0 between spaces, icons and texts and it looks horrible:
screenshot_1
screenshot_2
Is there a way / command with which I can enlarge the margin of spaces / icons / texts to the original size in these applications after theming? In the pictures I use Resources (net.nokyan.Resources) but it is also the same in Text editors (org.gnome.TextEditor) as well.
Thank You in advance!
